# Access modified localhost directory from different computers

Tags: apache, networking, ubuntu, localhost

First of all, I'm on ubuntu 12.10 and running latest apache patch. I know how to access the default localhost directory of my server from other computers. When I type in 192.168.1.** in a different computer, I can access the /var/www/ directory.

But what if I want to appoint that to a different directory? ***Where*** and ***how*** do I modify it? hosts, conf.d etc? And how can I access it with a domain name instead of the IP? Thanks ahead.

Comment: `192.168.1.**` isn't `localhost`. `localhost` is specifically defined as `127.0.0.1`. Your `192.168.1.**` is a local network IP address, which is *not* the same thing at all.

Comment: yes, I meant'the localhost directory of my server' from another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. You will most likely find a file named `default` and another named `default-ssl`. The `DocumentRoot` can be changed within this file. Remember to restart Apache...

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or...

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Or...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

It's not unusual to have several virtual hosts listed in `sites-available`, and remember that these configs have to have symbolic links in `sites-enabled` in order to be seen by Apache.

A Virtual Host file looks something like this...

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Further reading: [Apache Documentation - Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Comment: thanks, it works. What about 'And how can I access it with a domain name instead of the IP? Thanks ahead.'? It's only for my local network.

Comment: If you want to use a domain name, then you need to register one. You can create a fake domain name (i.e. local.myawesomeserver) but you'll only be able to use it after editing your `hosts` file and assigning your IP address to it, and that will only work for any machine that has an edited `hosts` file.

Comment: that clarifies many things. so I just need to register the ip and domain in the hosts file on clients. cool :)